# How to stop iconv-lite from automatically console.log the entire document

Tags: node.js

The `node.js` print all csv content in terminal when I run following code, I do not know why and how do I to fix it, I do not wanna `console.log` anything, and my code does not have `console.log` command, why does it print file content? help

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

const xlsxFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './csv/demo.csv')

const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(xlsxFilePath );
const encodedData = iconv.decode(fileBuffer, 'GBK');
fs.createReadStream(encodedData )
```